# Как оптимизировать данный код?

Tags: java, android

Пожалуйста помогите с оптимизацией, а то код работает, но на 3 пункта списка тратится 5 секунд (может и мало, но у меня то их будет где то 20!). Сразу предупреждаю что код выполнен по всем правилам инкостыляции:)

```
URL url = new URL("http://csgobets.890m.com/api/db/get_matches.php");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();
                dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(resultJson);
                JSONArray matches = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("matches");
                number = matches.length();
                cycle = 0;
                json = String.valueOf(matches);
                while (x != number) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, Integer.toString(x));
                    JSONObject match = matches.getJSONObject(x);
                    Log.e("match", String.valueOf(match));
                    MatchDetails[x] = String.valueOf(match);
                    TeamA[x] = match.getString("teamA");
                    TeamB[x] = match.getString("teamB");
                    CoefA[x] = match.getString("coefA");
                    Log.d("CoefA", CoefA[x]);
                    CoefB[x] = match.getString("coefB");
                    imgA = match.getString("imgA");
                    imgB = match.getString("imgB");
                    imgL = match.getString("imgL");
                    try {
                        InputStream imgAis = new java.net.URL(imgA).openStream();
                        ImgA[x] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imgAis);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        InputStream imgBis = new java.net.URL(imgB).openStream();
                        ImgB[x] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imgBis);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        InputStream imgLis = new java.net.URL(imgL).openStream();
                        ImgL[x] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imgLis);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    myMatches.add(new Match(TeamA[x], TeamB[x], CoefA[x], CoefB[x], 2, ImgA[x], ImgB[x], ImgL[x]));
                    x++;
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        populateList();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultJson;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Наугад такие вещи не делаются. Померяйте время выполнения отдельных блоков кода, тогда и понятней станет где тормоза. Вангую что основное время будет тратиться на кусок от `url.openConnection()` до завершения чтения из `inputStream`.

Comment: просьбы "памагите аптимизиравать код" запрещены. Вопрос будет закрыт.

Answer (score 2):

Зачем там столько try-catch?
Обработка исключений - это очень медленная операция.

---

Переформулирую для непонятливых:

Если исключения являются нормальным потоком исполнения, то их обработка, являющаяся чрезвычайно медленной операцией, вероятно, является основной причиной медленной работы. Следует переписать код так, чтобы исключения возникали только в исключительных ситуациях и не возникали при нормальном исполнении. Вероятно, это можно сделать с помощью каких-то проверок корректности данных.

Comment: Зачем вы оставляете комментарий как ответ?

Comment: @metalurgus, это ответ. Вопрос, как оптимизировать код. Если там не просто так стоят блоки try-catch, то очевидно, что именно это надо оптимизрировать, заменив их на некие проверки. Если блоки стоят просто так, то автор не только написал подозрительный код, но и не выполнил правило, требующее размещать минимальный пример, чем ввёл меня в заблуждение. Поэтому это ответ.

Comment: нет. Это комментарий. Он не дает ответа на вопрос, а лишь уточняет его.

Comment: @metalurgus, даёт. В нём предлагается заменить обработку исключений проверкой условий.

Comment: нет, не предлагается. В нем ничего не предлагается.

Comment: @metalurgus, дополнил. Но такие вещи надо бы самому додумывать из сказанного.

Comment: try-catch там уместен, т.к. `openStream()` кидает проверяемое исключение и от него никуда не уйти. Разве что можно было бы вынести повторяющийся код в метод. Ну и обрабатывать исключения как-нибудь получше, чем плохим `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: @Nofate, он уместен трижды на каждую итерацию цикла? При том, что сам цикл обёрнут в такой же? По мне, так это говорит о том, что человек именно игнорирует там падения, а не оборачивает просто по требования джавы.